# What does [...] mean for Reparse Point Target when dir /al is executed

Tags: windows, hardlink, dir, reparse-points

When I execute `dir \al` (Attribute: Reparse Points), I get a result that lists reparse points. The following output is easy enough to understand with columns being `Date Modified`, `Time Modified`, `Dir Type` (empty if it's a file), `File Size` in bytes (empty if it's a directory), and `Reparse Point Link [Reparse Point Target]`

> Directory of X:\Desktop\***
>
> 2013/10/17　　10:07　　<JUNCTION>　　　　Application Data [C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming]

However the following result shows **`[Reparse Point Target]` of `[...]` but what does it mean?** *(Side Note: `bin` seems to be a `File` when viewed through Windows' File Explorer.)*

> Directory of X:\Desktop\***\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs
>
> 2022/04/23　　11:08　　<JUNCTION>　　　　bin [...]

I am trying to figure what it means but **where can I find a documentation for deciphering the output of Windows' `dir` command?** The Microsoft's documentation for `dir` ([Docs / Windows Server / Windows Commands / Reference / dir](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir)) doesn't help much.

Lastly **is the following output result of `dir \al` (Attribute: Reparse Points), for a Hard Link file?**

> Directory of X:\Desktop\***\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\dev
>
> 2022/04/23　　11:08　　　　　　　　　　0　 console

Comment: While inside the `rootfs` folder, `fsutil.exe reparsePoint query "bin"` might reveal more information about that curious [...] entry.

Comment: @leeharvey1 As you probably have suspected, I have **WSL version 1 with Ubuntu-22.04** (`wsl -l -v`) installed. So, when I execute your specified command of `fsutil.exe reparsePoint query "bin"` at `rootfs`, I get multiple output lines with the last line's last segment showing `....usr/bin`. Thanks for the tip.